# What is $(x^7-x)mod(x^6-3)$ equal to?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, galois-theory, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I'm trying to use Rabins test for irreducibility over finite fields , but in part of the test you need to calculate $gcd(f,x^{p^{n_i}}-xmodf)$ where in my case p=7 and n=6,3,2 as I'm testing if $f(x)=x^6-3$ is irreducible over GF(7).

My trouble is I don't know how to calculate this modulo, I know how to do it for integers and I know that in my case it implies that $x^6=3$. But after this i'm stuck.

could anyone work me through how to find what $(x^7-x)mod(x^6-3)$ is equal to ?

Also is Rabins test a good go to for testing if a polynomial is irreducible over a finite field ? Or is there perhaps less cumbersome methods for higher degree's of f(x) where degree f(x)>3 and so doesn't strictly need to be factored into linear polynomials in order to be irreducible ? (just suggestions would suffice )

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen yes how silly of me, I meant GF(7) is rabins the best test ?

Comment: $3$ is a root of unity of order six in $GF(7)$. Therefore the zeros of $f(x)$ are of order $36$ (we cannot always conclude this, but this time no new prime divisors came, and it is plain). Because $m=6$ is the smallest positive exponent such that $36\mid 7^m-1$, we know that the the 36th roots of unity have minimal polynomials of degree six. Therefore $f(x)$ must be irreducible over $GF(7)$ (because the minimal polynomial is its factor). I dare guess that Rabin's test does exactly the same calculation (and applies more generally), so you should probably go thru with it.

Comment: Thank you Jyrki

Comment: @exodius Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Division algorithm:

$$x^7 - x = (x^6 - 3) (x) + (2x)$$

and this is valid because $\deg (2x) < \deg (x^6 - 3)$

So the remainder is $2x$.

Comment: Isn't this saying that $x^7-x=2xmod(x^6-3)$ ?

Comment: I thought that a=b mod n was equivalent to a=kn + b

Comment: Because i was seeking a if $a = x^7-x mod (x^6-3)$

Comment: ohh wait it can just be reaaranged to get it like that never mind

Answer (score 1):

Note that

$$x^7-x=x(x^6-3)+2x$$